# Random Integers Appear When Deleting Element in Linked List

Tags: c++, random, linked-list, integer

When I attempt to delete a certain element from a linked list, some of the elements end up somehow obtaining random values in place of their originals. What is the problem?

```
void removeSpaceShipPower(SpaceShip *x, int y)
{
    SpaceShip *current = x;
    SpaceShip *toDelete = NULL;
    SpaceShip *next = NULL;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->nextShip->power == y)
        {
            next = current->nextShip->nextShip;
            current->nextShip = next;
            toDelete = current->nextShip;
            free(toDelete);
            return;
        }
        current = current->nextShip;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    SpaceShip *freeList = new SpaceShip;
    freeList->power = 50;
    freeList->health = 100;
    SpaceShip *freeList2 = new SpaceShip;
    freeList2->power = 25;
    freeList2->health = 100;
    SpaceShip *freeList3 = new SpaceShip;
    freeList3->power = 75;
    freeList3->health = 100;
    SpaceShip *freeList4 = new SpaceShip;
    freeList4->power = 100;
    freeList4->health = 100;
    freeList->nextShip = freeList2;
    freeList2->nextShip = freeList3;
    freeList3->nextShip = freeList4;
    freeList4->nextShip = NULL;
    printSpaceShip(freeList);
    cout << getLowestPower(freeList) << endl;
    removeSpaceShipPower(freeList, 75);
    printSpaceShip(freeList);
}
```

Output:

```
Spaceship #1 Power: 50 Health: 100
Spaceship #2 Power: 25 Health: 100
Spaceship #3 Power: 75 Health: 100
Spaceship #4 Power: 100 Health: 100
25
Spaceship #1 Power: 50 Health: 100
Spaceship #2 Power: 25 Health: 100
Spaceship #3 Power: 9310088 Health: 9306304
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly tweaked your code to generate this:

```
SpaceShip* removeSpaceShipPower(SpaceShip *x, int y)
{
    SpaceShip *current = x;
    SpaceShip *toDelete = NULL;
    SpaceShip *next = NULL;
    // check if head of list is to be deleted
    if (current->power == y) {
       next = current->nextShip;
       free(current);

       return next;
    } 

    while(current->nextShip != NULL)
    {
        if(current->nextShip->power == y)
        {
            toDelete = current->nextShip;           // remember this address for later
            next = current->nextShip->nextShip;
            current->nextShip = next;               // splice out the node to be deleted
            free(toDelete);                         // delete the spliced node
            return;
        }
        current = current->nextShip;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Here is what is wrong with your original logic:

```
next = current->nextShip->nextShip; // next is two steps ahead of current
current->nextShip = next;           // current->nextShip points two steps ahead
toDelete = current->nextShip;       // you are deleting the wrong node!
free(toDelete);
```

In graphical terms, assume that you had the following linked list:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

If you were trying to delete 3, your original code would have ended up with this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL     -> 5 (dangling)
```

The reason you were seeing random integers is that you were accessing memory which had already been freed.  You could have also had a segmentation fault instead.

Comment: I just ran into another problem, it turns out the deleting the first node case is not working correctly. I'm getting random integers again when I try deleting the first node.